# Recovering GPT table after failed volume merge

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, mbr, gpt

Background.

I shucked a 14TB wd drive. I didn't realize it was exFAT and I wanted NTFS security features (for what it's worth). Upon finding out exFAT was hard to convert and I only had 1.3TB used (I should have just copied the drive data - I didn't) I thought it would be safe to split the drive into two volumes and convert and merge that way.

The partition manager I used did the split OK. I copied the data to the new NTFS volume and then at a later date converted the other volume too.

Yesterday I decided to merge the volumes (without thinking it through) and I deleted the empty volume, and then merged the two.

It failed.

Test disk is seeing the old two volumes in MBR mode but in GPT mode it's not showing correctly and saying the volumes are corrupt.

Disk genius free and mini tools are seeing the volumes (min tools partially).

Can I use the recovered volume partition data to rewrite the GPT table in Linux. Preferably in read only mode and copy the 1.3TB data to another drive and then wipe the 14TB one and restore the data to it?

just to add, I tried to write the volumes test disk saw in MBR mode to the drive so the drive has a MBR and GPT table.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting
Apart from your horrible spelling, your case description is much better here:
https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=12160
This makes me sad: As soon as people are posting on superuser.com, the text quality rises.

Comment: "Test disk is seeing the old two volumes in MBR mode" - Before I comment on this statement.  This a system or data disk? "so the drive has a mbr and gpt table." - That seems strange, it likely in reality has neither, which is the reason for some of your problem.

Comment: in very simple terms you can have both gpt and mbr partition table on a drive, @ramhound. I will update shortly

Comment: this topic would greatly benefit from screenshots IMO.

Answer (score -1):

Because only 1.3TB was stored on the drive, that was the life saver.

3 tools could see the data and recover it.

Drive Genius could see the GPT partitions prior to the re-partition.

Minitool Partition Wizard only see the second one properly which had the data and Testdisk could see both partitions but under the MBR scan.

Full recovery to another drive was achieved thanks to Testdisk.